# One to One relationship in SonataAdmin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

i trying to make admin page for Product which has relationship 1:1 with image.

Product

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
    class Product
    {

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Id
         * @var int
         */
         private $id = 0;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="product")
         */


               private $image;
  /**
     * @return Image
     */
    public function getImage(): ?Image
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @param Image $image
     */
    public function setImage(Image $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
        return $this;
    }
    }
```

Image

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="images")
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Id
     * @var int
     */
    private $id = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

  /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }
}
```

ProductAdmin

```
class ProductAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('image', 'sonata_type_admin', array('label' => 'Okładka', 'by_reference' => false,));
}
```

ImageAdmin

```
class ImageAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('file', 'file', array('label' => 'Okładka', 'required' => false))
            ->add('path', 'text', array('label' => 'Scieżka do pliku', 'required' => false));

    }
```

I setuped services correctly, but i can't edit product and after saving new one i geting error

> unable to find the object with id : 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to not initialize your $id

```
private $id = 0; // =====> this is a private $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes. Let's try to correct your code.

1. Just follow the tutorials and put right annotation for $id:

   ```
   /**
    * @var integer $id
    *
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;
   ```
2. Hope, that this is just a typo with "?Image":

   ```
   /**
    * @return Image
    */
    public function getImage() : Image
    {
         return $this->image;
    }
   ```
3. And finally.

   ```
    /**
     * Class ProductAdmin
     */
   class ProductAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
   {
        protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
        {
            $formMapper
                ->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', [
                         'btn_add'       => true,      //Or you can specify a custom label
                         'btn_list'      => 'list button!',     //which will be translated
                         'btn_delete'    => false,             //or hide the button.
                         'btn_catalogue' => 'messages', //Custom translation domain for buttons
                         'label'         => 'My image',
                     ], [
                         'placeholder'   => $this->trans('messages.no_images_message'),
                         'edit'          => 'standard',
                         'inline'        => 'standard',
                         'sortable'      => 'id',
                     ])
             ;
        }
   }
   ```